# Weird error with Ember controllers

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

I'm on Ember Cli version: 0.2.3

I'm currently exploring with Ember, and trying a very simple app.

I have this in my templates/about.hbs

```
<h1>About</h1>

<p>I'll write something interesting here</p>

<button type="btn btn=primary"{{action 'clickMe'}}>Click me!</button>
```

and in my controllers/about_controller.js

```
Blogger.AboutController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  actions: {
    clickMe: function() {
      alert('Something something');
    }
  }
});
```

when I click on the button i get this error, I checked the syntax and can't seem to catch what's wrong. I need some fresh eyes.

```
Uncaught Error: Nothing handled the action 'clickMe'. If you did handle the action, this error can be caused by returning true from an action handler in a controller, causing the action to bubble.
```

Now, I understand what the message is saying, but I don't know how to fix it yet.

Comment: [Naming conventions](http://www.ember-cli.com/#naming-conventions) are important, the file name should just be `about.js` and you should be using es6 modules for it.

Comment: @Kitler when I first created the about controller I had it named about.js though I got this error 

      `Uncaught Error:  Expected to find: 'controller:about' within 'blogger/controllers/about' but got 'undefined'. Did you forget to `export default` within 'blogger/controllers/about'?`

Comment: Well did you forget to export? :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ember probably can not find your controller. You can debug this using [ember inspector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ember-inspector/bmdblncegkenkacieihfhpjfppoconhi).  In any case you should be using ES6 conventions inside your ember cli project. You can get to know more about the subject [here](http://www.ember-cli.com/#using-modules).

Anyway, try to create `about` controller using command line by typing

```
ember generate controller about
```

and then add your action manually.

Comment: worked like a charm. though the code is very similar except the ```Blogger.AboutController``` that changed to ```export default ```
thanks @Mateusz Nowak

Answer (score 2):

Are you using ember cli or Ember starter Kit for your program.

If you are using Ember cli then you should create files like - 
app/templates/about.hbs
app/controllers/about.js
and you should make one entry in app/router.js too[I think you must have done that.]
Entry in router.js-

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('about');
 });
```

Now your template/about.hbs should be-

```
<h1>About</h1>

<p>I'll write something interesting here</p>

<button {{action 'clickMe'}}>Click me!</button>
```

and controllers/about.js should be-

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.ObjectController.extend({
actions:{
       clickMe: function() {
      alert('Something something');
    }
  }
});
```

After making all the above changes execute below command on CMD - 
ember server (this should start the server)

Your code should work if you do it in above pattern.
Naming conventions are very important in Ember.

Comment: Yes, the controller naming was incorrect. As @Kitler mentioned(ES6) the global variables have been replaced by ES6 modules. Sadly most examples out there are deprecated. Thanks for looking into this